# Using JS to check if integer is even or pressing q to quit

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop

The objective here is for the user to enter a number to determine whether it is even or to enter 'q' to quit the program.

```
    var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

    var i = 0;


    while (i <= 3) {
    var num = readlineSync.question("Enter q to quit, or enter an integer to continue?");
    if (num === 'q') {
    console.log("You have quit the application. Thanks for using.");
    break;
    }
   else if (num % 2) {
   console.log("You have entered an odd number");
   }
   else if (num !== 'q') {
   console.log("You have not entered a valid character. Please try again.");
   break;
   }
   else {
   console.log("You have entered an even number.");
   break;
   }

  }
```

Pressing q initiates the appropriate response and exits the program. Entering an odd number also generates the appropriate response. However if an even number is entered, the program does not generate the appropriate response and instead reads **You have not entered a valid character. Please try again**. What am I overlooking? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: is this nodejs? `require` is not part of javascript. What is `readline-sync`?

Comment: Yes this is node.js. Basically it prompts Node to read the script and console.log outputs the response

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are using anything beyond native javascript, you should tag it. Since I do not know node.js, I would have seen the tag and skipped this question. And someone else who does use node.js, who might have otherwise skipped this question because it was only tagged with javascript, will now know that is for node.js. :) I've added the node.js tag for you

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your third condition (num !== 'q').  It evaluates as true when you enter an even number.

Comment: so would another condition within that one be sufficient, ie (num !== 'q' && num = parseInt(num)) be sufficient?

Comment: You could do something like that but it might be cleaner to use modulus again to check for even.